# Equilibrium solutions of Coupled ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, systems-of-equations

The task at hand is to find an expression for the equilibrium solutions of the following system of ODEs:
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
X'=&X(1-X)-YX/(0.2+X) \\ Y'=&0.5YX/(X+0.2)-kY
\end{array}
\right.
$$
where $X(t)$ and $Y(t)$ represent a prey and predator population respectively, with constant $k$.

Attempted solution.
I have attempted to begin by letting $X'=Y'=0$ and then trying to solve for specific variables. But I am unsure as to what variable we should be solving for.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance.

Comment: Solve for $X$ and $Y$, of course! That's the only variables that there are ($k$ is only a parameter).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equilibrium points are the solutions for

$$
x(1-x)-\frac{x y}{x+0.2} = 0\\
\frac 12\frac{x y}{x+0.2}-k y = 0
$$

or

$$
(1,0),\ \ \left(\frac{0.4k}{1-2k}, \frac{0.04(5-12k)}{(2k-1)^2}\right), \ \ (0, 0)
$$

Using the linear approximation we can qualify those points. Now with the jacobian

$$
J_k = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{y x}{(x+0.2)^2}-2 x-\frac{y}{x+0.2}+1 & -\frac{x}{x+0.2} \\
 \frac{y}{2 (x+0.2)}-\frac{x y}{2 (x+0.2)^2} & \frac{x}{2 (x+0.2)}-k \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

calculated at the equilibrium points and then calculating their eigenvalues we have respectively

$$
(-1, 0.416667 - k),\ \ (\lambda_1(k), \lambda_2(k)),\ \ (1,-k)
$$

$\lambda_1(k)$ and $\lambda_2(k)$ are involved expressions so we show their behavior using a graphic representation. Red for $\lambda_1(k)$ and blue for $\lambda_2(k)$. Attached a stream plot for $k = 1$. In black the locus described for the second equilibrium point with $k$. There is also the possibility of Hopf bifurcations.

[image]

[image]